# where is the option in twitter to view my tweets?

Tags: twitter

where is the option in twitter to view my tweets?

I'm interested in viewing my tweets, the option used to be there but now the GUI seems to have changed and I can't find the option.

[image]

Comment: Click on the Profile link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clicking your profile picture there, where the arrow is drawn in the pic

Example:
[image]

**Note added by barlop**  yeah, the other profile pic(in the bottom left of the pic) doesn't bring up the page showing your tweets, but clicking the one where the arrow in the pic is, does.

Comment: you mean try clicking the profile picture OVER THERE, where you draw the arrow.. 'cos the profile pic in the bottom left doesn't bring up that screen

Comment: Good point. Thanks, @barlop.